# Contactus table schema

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have two HTML form in first form i am adding Id and product and second form is contact us form. I have created one table with column name is ID,Product,name,email,mobile.In first form i am adding id and product and rest of values are NULL,than form will redirect to contact us form there i am updating name,email,mobile..I am getting pop is updated successfully but when i checked in database there was no update....please help me

```
//insert code



<?php


try{

$product=$_POST['product'];
/*
$product2=$_POST['product2'];
$product3=$_POST['product3'];
*/
    // form data





    //database Connection details
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database="store";
    $error = "";

    $conn=mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die('Connection failed: ' . mysql_error());

    @mysql_select_db($database, $conn) or die("Could not select your database".mysql_error());


        $insertQuery = "Insert into contactus(Id,Product) values('null','$product')";

        $result = mysql_query($insertQuery);




    mysql_close($conn);
    header('Location: /newstore/contact.html');   

}

catch(Exception $e) {
    echo ("<script>alert('Something went terribly wrong. Please try again later.');location.href = ''../index.html';</script>");
    return false;
}

?>

//Update code


    <?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>


<?php

$_SESSION['user_name1']=$_POST['product'];
try{

    // form data
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
    $product=$_SESSION['user_name1'];


    //database Connection details
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database="store";
    $error = "";

    $conn=mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die('Connection failed: ' . mysql_error());

    @mysql_select_db($database, $conn) or die("Could not select your database".mysql_error());
;if ((strlen($name) < 3) or (strlen($email) < 3) or(strlen($mobile) < 3))
{
    echo ("<script>alert('Something went wrong with your data inserted. Please fill the form again.');location.href = '../newstore/index.html';</script>");
}else
{

        //$insertQuery = "Insert into contactus(Id,Name,Email,Mobile,Product) values('null','$name','$email','$mobile','$product')";

       //$UpdateQuery = "update contactus set Name='$name',Email='$email',Mobile='$mobile' where Product='$product' ";


    $UpdateQuery = "update contactus set Name='".$name."',Email='".$email."',Mobile='".$mobile."' where Product='$product' ";

        $result = mysql_query($UpdateQuery);

        if($result){
            echo "<script>alert('Thank You. Your Data Received Succefully.');location.href = '../newstore/index.html';</script>";
        }
        else
        {
           echo "<script>alert('Something went wrong with your data inserted. Please fill the form again.');location.href = '../newstore/index.html';</script>"; 
        }
    }

    mysql_close($conn);
}

catch(Exception $e) {
    echo ("<script>alert('Something went terribly wrong. Please try again later.');location.href = ''../newstore/index.html';</script>");
    return false;
}

?>
```

Comment: I tried but nothing is happing..................i tried this code also......$UpdateQuery = " update contactus set Name='$name',Email='$email',Mobile='$mobile' where Product='$product' ";

Comment: Try this way: `"update contactus set Name='".$name."',Email='".$email."',Mobile='".$mobile."' where id=('select count(*) from contactus') "` and make sure you are updating on correct id.

Comment: No man ....I am getting alert('Thank You. Your Data Received Succefully.') but when i am checking table  nothing is happing .

Comment: Update your question with `contactus` table schema. Did you get last inserted id from count?? `echo $UpdateQuery;exit;` and test it in your database directly.

Comment: You know when is type directly id or product value than its working       $UpdateQuery = "update contactus set Name='".$name."',Email='".$email."',Mobile='".$mobile."' where id='31' ";

Comment: Hello Indrasinh i tried your code.........echo $UpdateQuery;exit;....................i am getting out put like this .......................update contactus set Name='assdd',Email='asdd@gmail.com',Mobile='1231231231' where id=('select count(*) from contactus')

Comment: Sorry Indrasinh i am not understand from there...please help

Comment: Try this `update contactus set Name='".$name."',Email='".$email."',Mobile='".$mobile."' where id=LAST_INSERT_ID() "`

Comment: that  code is for insert and i want to update

Comment: Sure .. i did but same issue

Comment: same issue..not updated in database

Comment: actually  that id  is not retrieve from database .How can we solve this issue

Comment: You need to find another way to get last inserted id.

Comment: How many records you have in your table? First test your query in database if it works than try it in your app.

Comment: only 5 column id,name,email,mobile,product......id and product  values is added using first form and name email,mobile is NULL values .I want to update that null values using second form

Comment: When you submit first form you can get last inserted id there and store it in session to access later while update second form.

Comment: i  change the Updated code in question.................... $UpdateQuery = "update contactus set Name='".$name."',Email='".$email."',Mobile='".$mobile."' where Product='$product' ";

Comment: _Please_ don’t use the `mysql_` functions, they’re deprecated and will be **removed** in a future version of PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Comment: Yes martin i will do after some time....but first i want to resolve my issue...can you help me in this

Comment: Do you have any field named Product in your table??

Comment: yes i have product column   in contactus table

Comment: so are you using product column to store your id in it??

Comment: now i am trying to do using product column to update the database

Comment: After insert query do this: `$_SESSION['user_name1'] = mysql_insert_id();` and than access it like this this while update `where Product=".$_SESSION['user_name1'];`

Comment: Sorry Indrasinh Bihola still not updating in database

Comment: hey   Indrasinh Bihola....... my issue  is  resolved now  i did session code which you given to me before. I am really  very happy .You help me a lot... I am really appreciate